# Log in to an iCloud account programmatically, given the necessary credentials

Tags: ios, ios8, icloud, ensembles

Is there a way to log in to an iCloud account programmatically (assuming I have the UserID and Password)?  I am using Ensembles 1.0 and would like to have the user enter the iCloud credentials and the app will log into the iCloud account "automatically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The iCloud account used affects the entire device. No individual app can use an iCloud account other than the one the user may currently be logged into on the device.

Comment: Hi Rick... so, the user has to logoff and then logon to the iCloud account manually... what are the "best practices" regarding this? Ask them to logoff and logon and then notify the app so the connection can be tested?  SD